# VIsualizing the effect that only one predictor has on the outcome (R)

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization

So I have performed a logistic regression on a data set with multiple predictors. I want to graphically represent the relationship between the outcome and only one of the predictors. What would be the best way of doing this?

I am having a hard time figuring out how to graphically show the effect that predictor X has on Y independent of the other predictor terms.  I read something about partial residual plots but I do not know how to implement this in R or how it would apply to data with a binary outcome. Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked out the visreg package?

Comment: Wow thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TeachingDemos package for R has a couple of functions that may help: `Predict.Plot` and `TkPredict`.  These will take a fitted model object and plot the relationship between one of the predictor variables conditional on the other predictors and the response variable.  You can then change the values of the other predictors to see how the relationship changes.  This is not the same as "independent" of the other predictors, but could end up being more meaningful.

This does not show residuals, but as you mention, the residuals don't make much sense in a logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out. I am fairly new to all of this so I apologize if this question is elementary but conceptually how can I make the plot so that it is truly 'independent' of the other predictors

Comment: @user3813193, I don't think that you can make a plot of a logistic regression that is independent of the other predictors.